# My linked list isn't returning the proper values or updating a list properly

Tags: java, linked-list

When my program comes to this method it never seems to update the target value. If I input "dave" it will remain "dave" no matter how many calls to the method are made.

```
public Person lookup(String name){
    if(firstPerson == null){
          return null;
        }
    Person target = null;
    for (target = firstPerson; target != null; target = target.nextPerson){ 
         if(name.equals(target.name)){
              return target;
             }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return target; // replace this line
     }
```

If I add a friend via this addFriend method firstFriend will end up printing whatever the last added name was. If the inputted named were rob bill and travis
The output would be travis travis travis.

```
 public void addFriend(Person friend){   
        firstFriend = new Friend(friend, firstFriend);
    return; // replace this line


 public String friendString(){
    String friendList = "";
    if(firstFriend == null){
        return null;
        }
    for(Friend pointer = firstFriend; pointer != null; pointer = pointer.nextFriend){
            friendList = friendList + firstFriend.who.name + " ";
        }

    return friendList.trim(); // replace this line
}
```

Comment: Your lookup method is incorrect. There should not be an else statement. If it goes through the entire for loop without finding "target" it should then return null.

Comment: Thanks @Compass. So would my final return value then be null if I iterate through the list without finding the target?

Comment: Yes. In a contract model, your contract is *return the target if found*, ergo if not found, should return null. Your provided model instead honored the contract *return the target if it is first in the list, otherwise return null*.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the lookup is working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always return in the first iteration of the loop. If the person is found it's returned (the `if` branch), and if it isn't, `null` is returned (the `else` branch). Instead, you should keep iterating until you find the correct person or exhaust the list. The first condition, BTW, is a subset of the loop (if `firstPerson` is `null` target will just become `null` immediately), and can (should!) also be removed:

```
public Person lookup(String name){
    Person target = null;
    for (target = firstPerson; target != null; target = target.nextPerson) { 
         if (name.equals(target.name)) {
              return target;
         }
    }
    return target; // Or null explicitly - matter of taste.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your input in much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(name.equals(target.name)){
          return target;
         }
        else {
            return null;
        }
```

The else part needs to go away. The effect of this code is that it only checks the first value and if it is not the value that you want to look up  it is coming out straight away.

Change

```
return target; // replace this line
```

to `return null;`
and remove the else part mentioned above